# Как реализовать выбор картинки из предложенных в другой форме

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

На форме имеется PicBox, при нажатии на него, вызывается другая форма, в которой представлены возможные значения(картинки).Как мне передать ImageLocation выбранной в этой форме картинки в ПикБокс, который вызывал форму? Картинки мог бы расставить вручную, но их 81.Поэтому я создал их программно через массив.Как теперь присвоить событию Click по одной из них, чтобы она передала свой ImageLocation тому PicBox`у, который её вызывал? Аля выбор аватарки на сайте при регистрации, где тебе даются только определённые варианты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class FormWith81Pictures : Form
{

  private void FormLoad()
  {
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++)
    {
      boxes[i].Click += PicBoxClick;
    }
  }

  public string ImageLocation { get; set; }

  private void PicBoxClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    PictureBox box = sender as PictureBox;
    ImageLocation = box.ImageLocation;
    Close();
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
  }

  ...
}

public class FormAdd : Form
{
  ...

  // in some method
  FormWith81Pictures form81 = new FormWith81Pictures();
  if (form81.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
    PictureBox1.ImageLocation = form81.ImageLocation;
  }
}
```

Comment: В прошлый раз я передавал переменную через метку.Через написанный вами код я ни разу не работал, поэтому немного не осмыслю как передать его обратно в PicBox1 на предыдущей форме(которая вызывала эту).Не могли бы вы подсказать, как мне передать в форму Add в элемент PictureBox1, его свойство ImageLocation полученное в box?

Comment: Хм, всё бы ничего, но на Windows. ругается.Говорит нет такого в данном контексте.В форме Add.В вызываемой добавил System и, вроде, принял..Форма Add(вызывает):    items form3 = new items();
                if (form3.ShowDialog == Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    pictureBox11.ImageLocation = form3.ImageLocation;
                }

Comment: @Ricarnev Так как `using System.Windows.Forms;`, вероятно, присутствует в начале файла, namespace можно не писать.

Comment: теперь форма Add(вызывающая) ругается на условие целиком:
Ошибка CS0019 Оператор "==" невозможно применить к операнду типа "группа методов" и "DialogResult".
Вызываемая форма приняла новый вариант спокойно.

Comment: @Ricarnev Ох, скобочки пропустил :( - `form81.ShowDialog` **()**

Comment: спасибо больше! Вы сделали даже проще, чем я пытался.Ставлю как решение!)

Comment: @Ricarnev Рад был помочь. Успехов!

Comment: P.S. можете в моём втором вопросе выложить этот же код, поставлю как решение.Тоже самое хотел реализовать, только через то, что нашел на тот момент)

Comment: @Ricarnev Если тот вопрoс о том же, лучше его просто удалить, чтобы не плодить дубликаты.

Comment: Хорошо, удалю.Просто хотел тоже самое реализовать, только через метки.Тут получилось лучше.

Comment: и/или перенести код из него в этот вопрос - ссылка "править" под вопросом.

Comment: А там код навряд ли как-либо относится к этому.Он привязывался у меня к определённому клику.Вернее мозгов не хватает вставить его в метод, который подставлял бы значение в зависимости от элемента.В начале файла добавлялись public delegate void и public event